# Why does Microsoft use new EventHandler when connecting to an event

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, eventargs

Suppose I have a class that logs errors (ErrorLog). Every time an error is added to the log this class will raise an event (ErrorLog.EventErrorAdded) to notify observers that a new error is added to the log. This event has some data (ErrorLog.EventErrorAddadArgs).

A different class wants to observe these event. The constructor subscribes to ErrorLog.EventErrorAdded so that the method OnEventErrorAdded(object Sender, ErrorLog.EventErrorAddedArgs Args) is called.

I see a difference between how Microsoft subscribes to the event and how I would do it. Both methods seem to work. I don't understand the advantage of Microsoft's method. Anyone who does?

The code would be similar to:

```
public class ErrorLog
{
    public class EventErrorAddadArgs: EventArgs
    {
        ...
    }

    public EventHandler<EventErrorAddadArgs> EventErrorAdded;
    etc.
}

public class MyObserver
{
    private ErrorLog myErrorLog = new ErrorLog();

    public MyObserver() 
    {
        // observe myErrorLog.EventErrorAdded,
        // make sure that OnEventErrorAdded is called

        // my method would be:
        myErrorLog.EventErrorAdded += OnEventErrorAdded;

        // Microsoft however prefers the following method:
        myErrorLog.EventErrorAdded += new System.EventHandler<ErrorLog.EventErrorAddadArgs>(this.OnEventErrorAdded);
    }

    private OnEventErrorAdded(object Sender, ErrorLog.EventErrorAddedArgs Args)
    {
        ...
    }

    etc.
}
```

Both methods check syntax correctness during compiletime. Both methods work.
So my question is: what is the advantage of the "new System.EventHandler" method above my method of just mentioning the delegate function?

Comment: Microsoft haven't updated their code templates for this since the language changed to simplify the declaration syntax - but note that if you use `Resharper`, it *does* generate the simplified syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntactic difference: your way was introduced in C# 2.0 and the way MS have done it uses the original more verbose syntax of C# - [they are equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), though:

> ...the above syntax is new in C# 2.0. It is exactly equivalent to the C# 1.0 syntax in which the encapsulating delegate must be explicitly created using the new keyword: